# Ubuntu 17.10 - WiFi fails to resume

Tags: wireless, 17.10, suspend

I've seen quite a few posts for earlier versions of ubuntu with this problem, none of the solutions seemed to have worked.

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 laptop, it uses a Realtek RTL8723BE Wifi card.

Every time the laptop resumes from sleep the Wifi tries to connect again(I see it attempting to connect 3 times) and always fails until I later manually tell it to connect to my network.

This is a small niggle but it affects my experience in using it, can anyone help me figure out and fix this problem?

Thanks,

Lisa

journalctl --follow | tee /tmp/log.log

There was rather a lot of entries here, so I had to use pastebin;
https://pastebin.com/dM1tK7Mp

Comment: In a terminal window, execute the command `journalctl --follow | tee /tmp/log.log` Then suspend/resume. Inspect the log messages produced by `journalctl`. Also read `man pm-action`

Comment: First, you have omitted many messages, including those explaining your problem. Second, don't put additional information in the comments, Edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1026927/edit) your question and add the properly formatted info.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I am new to this style of formatting and I had tried. 

The log is very long, I was trying to narrow it down - obviously I went too far!